# Loop skips first number of the count

Tags: excel, vba

I am unsure why this is skipping what should be the next number. For example, if I input 5 the list then runs 7,8, etc, but the number 6 is dropped. Similar if I input 4 the list then runs 6,7, etc.

```
Sub CountFromInput()
Dim i As Integer
Dim start As Integer

start = InputBox(Prompt:="Input the first number", Title:="Number Input")
Range("b1") = start

For i = 2 To 14
    Cells(i, 2).Value = start + i
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that because `i=2` and `2+4` is `6`. You need to start with `i= 1` or is this a kind of trick question?

Comment: No trick intended. I have i = 2 to 14 because the input box puts the initial number in row 1 and I want rows 2 to 14 filled with the concurrent numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CountFromInput()
Dim i As Integer
Dim start As Integer

start = InputBox(Prompt:="Input the first number", Title:="Number Input")
Range("b1") = start

For i = 1 To 13
    Cells(i+1, 2).Value = start + i
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's working as expected. If I understand your changes, this started the loop count 1 row down through the use of  'i + 1'  in the loop, and for this reason the count had to be changed to '1 To 13' because the '+1' needed to be account for to achieve the end goal of 14 increments.